# jQuery Datepicker only shows once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a textbox on a form, and I create a datepicker like this:

```
$("#txtBirthDate").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: '1920:2999',
                    maxDate: '+0d',
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
```

This works fine, but what happends is:

I press the textbox, the datepicker appears nicely, select a date. but then if I want to select another date, I first need to click on another field, and then click back on the birthdate field. When I press the birthdate field the second time without clicking another field first the datepicker doens't show..

What am I missing here?

HTML Code:

```
<label>Birthdate</label>
<input type="text" name="txtBirthDate" id="txtBirthDate" class="input" readonly='true' value="<?echo $_POST["txtBirthDate"]; ?>" />
```

Comment: Ok I've added the HTML code...

Comment: I've tried your code and it's working, I wrapped your JS code with $(function() { }); do you have that? and maybe old version of jquery ? because for me it's working on and on ...

Comment: Yes I've wrapped it in the $(function(){}); I know the original demo of jquery works also, I think maybe it is because I use custom styling of the textbox but I don't know for sure....

Comment: copy code into blank page where will be only datepicker and textfield, if it works problem might be elsewhere

Comment: Ok I will check if I can find the problem.. Once I found it I will post the solution.. If anyone has other options left, please let me know! Thanks riso so far!

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem was the focus. The field didn't loses focus after a date selection. Solved with:

```
$("#txtBirthDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1920:2999',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    maxDate: '+0d',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#txtBirthDate").blur();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Thank you for trying to solve the issue with me!

Answer (score 0):

It Happens once with me just follow the article and see what is different but i think that you miss :

```
 showButtonPanel: true,
```

in your code .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The very simple answer that worked for me was to include this line

```
 $('#ui-datepicker-div').remove();
```

prior to initializing your datepicker elements.